# How to retrieve the attribute class powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am attempting to get license status for a list of users. I will do something based on licence status.

e.g licence user output:

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre@contoso.com" | fl

DeletionTimestamp              : 
ObjectId                       : 
ObjectType                     : User
AccountEnabled                 : True
AssignedLicenses               : {class AssignedLicense {
                                   DisabledPlans: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
                                   SkuId: 6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900
                                 }
                                 }
```

non-licence user output :

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre@contoso.com" | fl

DeletionTimestamp              : 
ObjectId                       : 
ObjectType                     : User
AccountEnabled                 : True
AssignedLicenses               : {}
```

I do not know how to retrieve it with AzureAD PowerShell. How to retrieve the SkuId from within `AssignedLicenses` attribute?

```
#for licence user
if($AzureADUser.SkuId -eq '6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900') 
{
 do something...
}

#for non-licence user
elseif($AzureADUser.AssignedLicenses -eq $null)
{
do something...
}
```

Last update :

```
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre@contoso.com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AssignedLicenses

DisabledPlans SkuId                               
------------- -----                               
{}            6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900
```

non-licence user:

```
 Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre2@contoso.com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AssignedLicenses
```

nothing is returning

Comment: I can't test the command but I would say you first need to expand the property `AssignedLicenses` with `Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre@contoso.com" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AssignedLicenses`.

Comment: @ManuP I have updated my question. you can see last update section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the SkuID directly like this.

```
(Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre2@contoso.com").AssignedLicenses.SkuID
```

The Select-Object state as seen in your question does also work, provided there are at least one license. Otherwise, there will be nothing to return.

For your user that returns nothing, you can run the following, which will indicate that the number of assigned licenses is equal to 0.

```
(Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "Andre2.contoso.com").AssignedLicenses.count
```

You could also grab all your users and their licenses using:

```
$SKus = Get-AzureAdSubscribedSku  | Select SkuPartNumber,SkuID
$Users = Get-AzureADUser -All $true 
$Users | Select {$_.UserPrincipalName,$_.AssignedLicenses.SkuID}
```

This Will list all your users and the assigned licenses. The AssignedLicenses SKU ID will be null for the AD user without any licenses.

From there, you could determine what SKUs ID are associated to which Sku Part Name (to determine if this is a power by license, an O365 premium license, etc...) by associating your SkuIDS to the name in the $Skus hashtable.